# Selenium: content dynamic content loading endlessly

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to download numerous annual accounts in pdf format from an open-source database in Belgium.

I want to use selenium to do that.

However, the dynamic content is endlessly loading when a search term is entered.

*HAVE:*
[image]

*WANT:*
[image]

Everything works fine when I do the same steps manually. I tried to insert some timeouts here and there but it does not solve the issue.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time 

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("http://cri.nbb.be/bc9/web/catalog?lang=F")



search_by_name = WebDriverWait(driver, 5, 0.25).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable([By.XPATH , '/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/form[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]']))

actions.move_to_element(search_by_name).click().perform()


search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/form[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/input')

search_box.send_keys("Anheuser-Busch InBev")
search_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason for doing that via WebDriver? The more reliable way would be using direct HTTP calls without the browser and unreliable UI - to replicate proper calls just observer Network tab in dev tools

Comment: Hi thanks for the pointers, I spent the last 4 hours trying to get it to work through XHR without success. I'm only getting nonsense results because I need to glue selenium with the requests library.

I'm receiving an error message at the end of my html

`Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.<br/>Your support ID is: 11152196027458031700.`

Could you recommend any articles or books I could use to help me with getting data from ajax queries or POST requests? 

Ultimately, I need to download .pdf files hidden behind "on-click" events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @PiotrM. You must use API if given any.
Having said that, you are using absolute xpaths, which may get clumsy.
Here is what I have refactored, and it works until what you've shown in the query.

```
driver.get("http://cri.nbb.be/bc9/web/catalog?lang=F")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='navTab']//li[contains(@class,'last')]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Banque']"))).send_keys("Anheuser-Busch InBev")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='page_searchForm:actions']//button").click()
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked but since I suck at using xpaths it blocks right after when I try to make selenium click on a company name. I need to read up on xpaths. XHR calls didn't work either. I need to glue selenium with the requests library otherwise I don't have javascript to generate dynamic content.